# Create reusable Redux connector (with the same mapState and mapDispatch) - having TypeScript issues

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, typescript-typings, higher-order-functions

Here's the component that can optionally render either a string (not being connected to a Redux store) or select box.

```
export function Content(props: ContentProps) {
  const { language } = props;

  if (!props.setLanguage) {
    return (
      <div>{language}</div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Select
      language={language}
      languages={languages}
      onChange={e => {
        props.setLanguage!(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

This code works perfectly fine

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  language: state.language,
});

const mapDispatch = {
  setLanguage,
};

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatch);

const ConnectedContent = connector(Content);

function App() {
  return (
    <ConnectedContent />
  );
}
```

But the thing is that I would need additional enhancements so connector must be reusable, something like

```
//type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

interface LoadingProps {
  loading?: boolean;
}

const withLoading = <P extends {}>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) => (props: P & LoadingProps) => (
  <>
    {props.loading && <div>Loading</div>}
    <Component {...props as P} />
  </>
);

function getConnectedComponent(Component: React.ComponentType) {
  const ComponentWithLoading = withLoading(Component);

  return connector(ComponentWithLoading);
}

const ConnectedContent = getConnectedComponent(Content);
```

But I don't know how to properly add types/generics into getConnectedComponent function. With inferring I am getting

```
Error:(24, 48) TS2345: Argument of type '(props: ContentProps) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
  Type '(props: ContentProps) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Property 'language' is missing in type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' but required in type 'ContentProps'.
```

Working example is on https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-snowflake-b5r89
As well pushed to GitHub https://github.com/hitrov/reusable-redux-connector

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the connector should be reusable", or what "additional enhancements" you're referring to.  It *is* reusable already.  The function returned from `connect(mapState, mapDispatch)` is ready to accept whatever component you passed in, so it *already* does what your notional `getConnectedComponent` wants to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, yes, if I export this connector variable - it would. But imagine that I would need additional enhancements to a component before passing it to connector (e.g. apply HOC to it) - and that’s why I must have a function that receives component as an argument and then applies connector to it

Comment: No, there's no "enhancements" that are needed, and I don't know where you're getting that idea. Any component can be passed to that `connector()` function, and it will work. Period.

Comment: you're telling me that i don't need while i do=) i have added the example above - imagine that i need to apply withLoading HOC before or after passing to connector. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: That use of a `withLoading` HOC is specific to your own application.  My point is that as far as React-Redux is concerned, there is nothing else that has to be done in order to successfully call `const ConnectedComponent = connector(MyComponent)`.  At this point I don't know what the actual question is, tbh.